# Проблема с нативным запросом в H2

Tags: sql, hibernate, h2

Используется hibernate и h2.
При попытке изменить уровень изоляции транзакции нативным запросом получаю 42001-199 ошибку. Изначально предполагал, что SESSION является ключевым словом и поместил его в кавычки, однако это не помогло.

Стектрейс:
[image: stacktrace]

Код запроса:
[image: query]

При этом, если сделать такой же запрос через H2 console, то проблем не будет. Полагаю проблема именно в каком-то из используемых слов, либо их связке.

Comment: в ошибке есть [*] - так и должно быть?

Comment: @NovitskyDenis, нет, не должно. Это говорит о синтаксической ошибке в слове SESSION. Однако запрос делался в соответствии со спецификациями h2. И мне не совсем понятно, где тут может быть ошибка.